# Alpaca form : upload field error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, forms, mongodb, upload

I make a form with Alpaca for a node.js site. This form contains an upload field which send file immediatly to a Mongo database (and to a "upload" folder) after the user has selected it. 
The files are correctly sent, but an error message appears for each file :

> Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1
>   column 1 of the JSON data

Here the Alpaca code (only the part of upload field) :

```
$("#form1").alpaca({
                "view": "bootstrap-create",
                "schema": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "addFilesForm": {
                            "type":"string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "options": {
                    "fields":{
                        "addFilesForm": {
                            "type": "upload",
                            "label": "Fichier(s) joint(s)",
                            "upload": {
                                "url":"/attachments",
                                "showUploadPreview": false,
                                "autoUpload": true,
                                "maxFileSize": 25000000,
                                "maxNumberOfFiles": 3
                            }                    
                        }
                    },
                    "form":{
                        "attributes":{
                            "action":"/demande",
                            "method":"post",
                            "enctype": "multipart/form-data"
                        },
                        "buttons":{
                            "submit":{}
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

and the layout.jade :

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='bower_components/alpaca/dist/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js')

        script(type='text/javascript', src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js')
        link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js')
        link(href='stylesheets/style.css', rel='stylesheet')
        // alpaca
        link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='bower_components/alpaca/dist/alpaca/bootstrap/alpaca.min.css' )
        script(type='text/javascript', src='bower_components/alpaca/dist/alpaca/bootstrap/alpaca.js')
        link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='bower_components/alpaca/dist/lib/jquery-file-upload/css/jquery.fileupload.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='bower_components/alpaca/dist/lib/jquery-file-upload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css')
        script(src='bower_components/alpaca/dist/lib/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js')
        script(src='bower_components/alpaca/dist/lib/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js')
        script(src='bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js')
        script(src='bower_components/alpaca/dist/lib/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js')
        script(src='bower_components/alpaca/dist/lib/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js')

    body
        block content
        block content2
```

Thank you and sorry for my english, I'm French